# Formatting Date Value Using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan

How can I format the below XML date element in XSLT version1.0 ? The `GenerationTime`  has to be formatted in pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` in the output XML.

```
<Values>
  <value name="GenerationTime">Tue Dec 29 14:32:53 UTC 2020</value>
<Values>
```

Here is what I found from my product's (Intergation Server) documentation

> When executed, the XSLT service calls an external XSLT engine to convert the XML data.
> The external XSLT engine must be Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)-compatible. By
> default, Integration Server includes the Xerces parser and the Xalan XSLT style sheet
> processor from the Apache Software Foundation.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using? This could use help from some extension functions, if your processor supports them.

Comment: Also your input example is ambiguous: we need to know if the day and hour values are already zero-padded.

Comment: Please always say which version of XSLT you are using. It makes a big difference.

Comment: @MichaelKay My xslt version is 1.0 . Thanks!

Comment: @michael.hor257k  Thanks for the inputs. the processer used is Xalan. I have added the details in the question now. and the day hour values are always zero padded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xalan supports the EXSLT [str:tokenize()](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) extension function, so you could do something like:

```
<xsl:template name="reformat-date">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <!-- extract dateTime components -->
    <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="str:tokenize($input, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mmm" select="$tokens[2]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="$tokens[3]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="time" select="$tokens[4]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="$tokens[6]"/>
    <!-- convert MMM to month number -->
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="string-length(substring-before('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', $mmm)) div 3 + 1" />
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$year"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($month, '-00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($day, '-00')"/>
    <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$time"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Demo**: http://xsltransform.net/6qCcdd5

Comment: this is what i was most confused about when i tried it on my own ` <xsl:variable name="month" select="string-length(substring-before('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', $mmm)) div 3 + 1" />
`

Comment: Not sure what the source of confusion is.

Comment: I meant when i tried to figure out ,before your answer. it helps, thank you!

Comment: I see. You could also handle it using an `xsl:choose` statement with 12 `xsl:when` clauses.

Comment: I have asked a followup question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518537/converting-date-from-a-timezone-to-utc-xslt-1-0 . I also want to convert the date value to a different timezone if its not in UTC. Can i do that?

Comment: If you're using Xalan then you're presumably using Java which means you could be using Saxon which means you would have access to all the date and time handling functions in XSLT 2.0 and 3.0, which would make your life much easier...

Comment: To be precise, having "access to all the date and time handling functions in XSLT 2.0 and 3.0" would not help in *this* case, because the input is not a dateTime. It would make life easier with the follow-up question, though.