# converting date from a timezone to UTC XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

How can I format the below XML date element in XSLT version1.0 ? The `GenerationTime`  has to be formatted in pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` in the output XML with the date value in `UTC`.

xslt processer used is xalan

```
<Values>
  <value name="cardGenerated">yes</value> 
  <value name="GenerationTime">Tue Dec 29 14:32:53 EST 2020</value>
<Values>
```

the output would look like

```
 <Values>
  <value name="cardGenerated">yes</value> 
  <value name="GenerationTime">2020-12-19T19:32:53Z</value>
<Values>
```

Comment: This is not possible using XSLT 1.0 alone. The offset between timezones is not constant (esp. when the timezone is a daylight-saving timezone) and you need to lookup the relevant offset from an external source such as the [Olson database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). IIRC, XSLT 3.0 has an optional specification for this.

Comment: @michael.hor257k in case of `EST` looking at the date value can't we know if its observing daylight savings and calculate the offset accordingly? other than daylight savings what else is required to determine a time zone's offset? in my case the possible time zones are EST, EDT and IST only.

Comment: If your data provider is careful about distinguishing between EST and EDT, you could use that to calculate the offset as either -05:00 or -04:00. And if IST means Indian Standard Time (as opposed to Israel Standard Time), then that's constant at 05:30. Once you know the offset, you can proceed as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196920/3016153.

Comment: This is assuming your dates are recent. I don't know what rules apply to historical dates. For example, India did observe DST as recently as 1971.

Comment: @michael.hor257k the dates will always be something from the future always. so it will all be recent.

Comment: Well, just keep in mind you are treading on thin ice here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k what can be the repercussion here?

Comment: An error of 1 hour?

Comment: @michael.hor257k but if the data distinguishes between EDT and EST . would that error still be occurring for some other reasons?

Comment: Because offsets may change for political reasons.